# API to try out for free with pagination, sorting and filtering

Tags: api, testing

Do you know of some open APIs to try out which have GET requests with filtering, sorting and pagination?

Comment: Now might be a good time to take [the site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), so you can make sure you're following our community standards. Asking for service recommendations isn't allowed.